# Creating a url string to get a favicon in java

Tags: java, android, favicon

I am trying to get a favicon from a website with the following method. I tried to avoid // problems and decided to use a URL object.

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(URL src) {
        try {
            URL url = src;
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am running

```
Bitmap faviconBitmap = getBitmapFromURL(new URL("http", "www"+url, "/favicon.ico"));
```

with my url set to: `url = imdb.com`

but I am failing and getting the following error:

```
01-24 20:01:33.702: W/System.err(8678): java.io.IOException: Illegal character in authority at index 22: http://www.nytimes.com
01-24 20:01:33.702: W/System.err(8678): /favicon.ico
```

any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: i've used your code ,but i have get error "java.io.IOException" , do you have any idea that how can i solve it? i also tried to use url.trim() but i wast be able to use method "trim()" as it was undefined

Comment: @Sasa If you still need help, please post a new question of your own. Be sure to give relevant code to show what you did. Also include a link to this question to show that you have done your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a newline or some other character at the end of `url` after "nytimes.com".

Comment: To add to this diagnosis, the OP can use `url.trim()` to remove unwanted (preceding and trailing) whitespace.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i've used the code above ,but i have get error "java.io.IOException" , do you have any idea that how can i solve it? i also tried to use url.trim() but i wast be able to use method "trim()" as it was undefined